# Upload photo to Facebook graph API - an unknown error has occured

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-8

Ok so I need a bit of help. This is what im doing so far.

I have used the Web Authentication broker example to pull my Access token for facebook (of course I added the 'publish_stream' scope to ensure I can post), and save it in localsettings as such:

```
function callbackFacebookWebAuth(result) {
    var url = result.responseData;

    var param1 = url.split("&");
    var param2 = param1[0].split("=");

    localSettings.values["Facebook.AccessToken"] = param2[1];

}
```

This works fine. Success.

Then, I am attempting  to upload a picture as such:

```
        var accessToken = localSettings.values["Facebook.AccessToken"];
        console.log(accessToken);

        var blob = canvas.toDataURL('multipart/form-data');
        console.log(blob);
        var filename = "photo.jpg";
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("access_token", accessToken);
        data.append("message", "test");
        data.append("source\"; filename=\"" + filename + "\"", blob);


        WinJS.xhr({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=" + accessToken,
            data: data,
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log("success");
        }, function (errorResponse) {
            var result = JSON.parse(errorResponse.responseText);
            console.error(result.error.message);

        });
```

The code seems like it should work. I have tested this by posting text only to /feed and it works. However when posting to /photos I run into issues.

I have converted the Canvas content to a dataUrl ('multipart/form-data' as suggested for this POST command)

I use the hack that Synergist suggested in this thread:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/0d23db45-afea-4886-b3ca-522a6919c9f7

However  I get the following Error:

```
(#1) An unknown error occurred
```

So now I'm stuck.

I've googled all day to no avail, so I am reaching out to the community for help. Can someone take a look at the code and tell me what I might be doing wrong??

Would much appreciate it!

Im using Visual Studio by the way; this is for a Windows 8 app.

Comment: OK I fixed it guys; here is how.

instead of: 
    `var blob = canvas.toDataURL('multipart/form-data');` 
I used `var blob = canvas.msToBlob();` 
Success!! Hope this helps other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I fixed it guys; here is how.

instead of:

```
var blob = canvas.toDataURL('multipart/form-data');
```

I used

```
var blob = canvas.msToBlob();
```

Success!! Hope this helps other people.